# Docker modified node container not connecting or seeing mongo db container within docker swarm overlay network

Tags: node.js, mongodb, docker, docker-swarm, docker-network

I have a docker swarm service that uses mongodb, mongo-express and a custom node image. I have created a simple docker yaml file to launch them all together.

```
version: '3.1'

services:
  mongo:
    image: mongo:4.0.6-xenial
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME:
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD:

  mongo-express:
    image: mongo-express
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME:
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD:
    ports:
    - "8081:8081"

  backend:
    image: backend
    ports:
     - "2222:2222"
```

Now I know that docker swarm automatically creates a default overlay network among all the nodes.
My docker inspect network displays all the containers within the network.
I can see the backend connected using localhost:2222 and mongo-express using localhost:8081.

My problem is the backend is not connecting, nor can it even see the mongo database.
I tried ssh-ing into the mongo-express container, pinged localhost:27017 successfuly, then pinged localhost:2222 successfuly.

However, trying to ping/curl mongo-express or mongodb from the backend container wields nothing, its like the ports arent even visible. (localhost:2222 works but localhost:8081 or localhost:27017 don't).

EDIT: I've ssh'd into the backend container again after copying mongo's ip address from docker inspect network, then were able to curl successfully 10.0.5.8:27017.
Why isn't it on the localhost?

Answer (score 2):

Each container has it's own IP address. This implies that within a docker container, `localhost` refers to itself. This is why you cannot expect to reach the mongo container IP address from the mongo-express container using `localhost`.

Docker compose and swarm provide us with a convenient way to address containers by their *service name* as defined in the docker-compose.yml file.

So from the *mongo-express* container, connect to mongo using `mongo:27017`.